# How to stop losing proper location/url when smooth scrolling to hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I have a few issues... I'm building my site with bootstrap/jquery. I'm using bootstrap nav and all nav links are hash links to different containers on the same page.

Issue #1
When using the method below to 'hijack' the link I lose the URL address thus look the ability for people to grab the link and share or link to it later.

Issue #2
There are a few other pages with content that aren't on the homepage. So obviously when users click on the link /somepage/#photography doesn't work. Is the only solution here to not use relative links?

```
<nav>
  <a href="#photography">Photography</a>
</nav>

// smooth scroll from navigation
$('nav a').click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  var $section = $($(this).attr('href'));
  scrollToObject($section);
});
```

Comment: include the function `scrollToObject` as well. Probably best to make a fiddle/snippet overall for us to play/experiment with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** the reason for losing the hash at the end of the URL is because the call to `evt.preventDefault()` is preventing the hash from being added.

I am not 100% sure on the inner-workings of the scroll effect in `scrollToObject()`, but if you can provide a callback function when the scrolling is complete you could then add `location.assign( evt.target.hash );` which will add the hash to the URL [(and it will show up in the user's history.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) *Of course, you can get the hash value from the anchor object, event, etc.*

You can read about the location interface in js on MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

**Issue 2:** You could actually accomplish this once again using `location.assign()`. Once again, without seeing all of your code, you can create a conditional in a callback and then send the user back to the page with the scrolling anchors: `location.assign( location.origin + '/' + evt.target.hash )`.